# How to remove numbers from references in latex article?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I do not know how to remove the numbers from references in the following latex. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, amsmath,amssymb, aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\title{Detecting Local Units in {\bf  {\it C. elegans}} Nervous System}% Force line breaks with \\
\thanks{C.elegans}%



blah bla blah 


\nocite{*}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}


\bibitem{parcellation1}Brodmann K., (1909) Vergleichende Lokalisationslehre der Grosshirnrinde. Johann Ambrosius Barth Verlag, Leipzig.
brosius Barth Verlag, Leipzig.
\bibitem{parcellation2}Penfield W., Boldrey, E., (1937) Somatic motor and sensory representation in the cerebral cortex of man as studied by electrical stimulation. Brain 60: 389-443.
\bibitem{parcellation3}Toga A. W., Thompson P. M., Mori S., Amunts K., and Zilles K. (2006). Towards multimodal atlases of the human brain. Nat. Rev. Neurosci. 7: 952-966. $doi: 10.1038/nrn2012$




\end{thebibliography}



\end{document}
```

The above is the codes, but I can't figure out why it produces number too. Thanks

Comment: `\bf \it {\it ` ????

Comment: The `revtex4-1` document class requires the use of numeric-style citation call-outs. If you don't show the entry numbers in the bibliography, how are readers supposed to make the connection between citation call-outs in the body of the text and the entries in the bibliography?

Comment: I want to refer with names of authors

Comment: Maybe: \bibitem[Brodmann]{parcellation1}Brodmann K.,... (?)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in a comment:

> I want to refer with names of authors

To create authoryear-style citation call-outs while using the `revtex4-1` document class (which automatically loads the `natbib` package), your best best is to (a) learn how to use BibTeX, (b) choose a bibliography style that generates authoryear-style citation call-outs, and (c) provide the instruction

```
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round}
```

in the preamble. And, of course, use `\citet` and `\citep` instructions to create the citation call-outs.

You don't appear to be using BibTeX, though. If you build the bibliography by hand, you need to provide some information in the optional argument of each `\bibitem` command, as is done in the code shown below.

If you wish to insert a bit of whitespace between the bibentries, I suggest you provide the following command in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\bibsep{1ex}}
```

A closing comment: Creating a bibliography entirely by hand is seriously tedious, and it is likely to be error-prone. You'll do yourself a huge favor by learning how to use BibTeX to create formatted bibliographies.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,amsmath,amssymb,aps]{revtex4-1}

% Modify the behavior of the natbib package:
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round} 

\begin{document}
\preprint{APS/123-QED}
\title{Detecting Local Units in \textit{C.\ elegans} Nervous System\thanks{C.~elegans}}
\maketitle

\citet{parcellation1}

\citep{parcellation2}

\citet{parcellation3}

blah 

blah

blah

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Brodmann(1909)]{parcellation1}Brodmann K. (1909) Vergleichende Lokalisationslehre der Grosshirnrinde. Johann Ambrosius Barth Verlag, Leipzig.

\bibitem[Penfield and Boldrey(1937)]{parcellation2}Penfield W., Boldrey, E. (1937) Somatic motor and sensory representation in the cerebral cortex of man as studied by electrical stimulation. Brain 60: 389--443.

\bibitem[Toga et~al.(2006)]{parcellation3}Toga A. W., Thompson P. M., Mori S., Amunts K., and Zilles K. (2006). Towards multimodal atlases of the human brain. Nat.\ Rev.\ Neurosci.\ 7: 952--966. doi: \url{10.1038/nrn2012}.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
\section*{Bibliography}
\begin{thebibliography*}{}
\bibitem[Abramowitz and Saunders, 2008]{Abramowitz2008}
Abramowitz, A. I., and Saunders, K. L. (2008). 
\newblock Is polarization a myth?
\newblock {\em The Journal of Politics, 70(2), 542-555.}
\end{thebibliography*}
```